# Query to suggest top 15 most active users who are not yet subscribed by user

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have 3 tables with structure as below.

```
 tbl_activities (id, activity_type, user_id)
 tbl_subscriptions (id, subscriber_id, subscribed_id)
 tbl_users (id, user_name)
```

User can do activity such as like or comment. He can also subscribe to many users. Now I want suggest some user for him base on activity type and avoid his current subscribing users.

Let say user "A" has id=1
=> I want to suggest 15 users to user "A" by most active user (user who have lots of activities) and avoid current subscribing users of user "A".

I used this query, but it takes around 15seconds to finish.

```
SELECT id, user_name FROM tbl_users 
WHERE id IN (
   SELECT t.user_id FROM (
      SELECT act.user_id 
      FROM tbl_activities act 
      INNER JOIN tbl_users u 
      ON act.user_id=u.id 
      WHERE u.id NOT IN (
         SELECT s.subscribed_uid 
         FROM tbl_subscriptions s 
         INNER JOIN tbl_users u1 
         ON s.subscribed_uid=u1.id 
         WHERE s.subscriber_id=1
      ) 
      GROUP BY act.user_id 
      ORDER BY COUNT(act.user_id) 
      DESC LIMIT 0,15
    ) AS t
)
```

I know it is very slow because of query "in and not in". But I could not find the best solution.

Appreciate your share about better query to solve this problem.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so (you haven't), provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so (again, you haven't), provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem by adding index to related fields in those 3 tables. It speeds up around 300 times from 15s to 50ms.